# what it is the opposite of comment?

Tags: terminology, programming, technology

In programming **commenting**: To disable a section of source code by converting it into a comment. If you do not want to run this line of code, just comment it out!

But my question what is the opposite of *comment it out*?
is it *disable comment* or just *don't comment it out*?

For example:
In my daily routine as a programmer, customers always say they want some features, then after some time they don't need them anymore, So I just comment on that part of the code I add! But after some time they want that feature again, So (what if I want to say I disable that comment)

Comment: I don't think there's a standard term (I've seen "uncomment", "(re)enable", etc). Since this is essentially about programming jargon, you might get a better answer on one of the programming sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Uncomment** is the usual opposite of comment in programming contexts. It is commonly used in computing circles although it hasn't made it into dictionaries (I did not find it in Merriam-Webster, Collins, Macmillan, or OED online).

It is defined in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uncomment) as "1. (programming, transitive) To convert (text that has been commented out) back into source code so that it will no longer be ignored by the compiler or interpreter." ("Uncomment", Wiktionary, as of Nov 22, 2022.)

[YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/uncomment) has a similar entry.

You can also find it used in many programming manuals and other documentation, e.g. from [IBM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/no/planning-analytics/2.0.0?topic=feeders-commenting-uncommenting-lines-code): "You can use the Comment/Uncomment feature of the Rules Editor to comment or uncomment manually entered lines of code or commentary."

Comment: Good answer. I take it that 'uncomment' isn't used additionally for 'convert [text that never was source code] to source code'?

Comment: I was in computer programming about 40 years, and I only rarely heard "uncomment".

Comment: @HotLicks — It’s the name of the menu option in several modern IDEs.  BBEdit for one.